# What is the meaning of "non temporal" memory accesses in x86

Tags: x86, sse, assembly

This is a somewhat low-level question.  In x86 assembly there are two SSE instructions:

> `MOVDQA xmmi, m128`

and

> `MOVNTDQA xmmi, m128`

The IA-32 Software Developer's Manual says that the *NT* in MOVNTDQA stands for *Non-Temporal*, and that otherwise it's the same as MOVDQA.

My question is, what does *Non-Temporal* mean?

Comment: Note that SSE4.1 `MOVNTDQA xmmi, m128` is an NT load, while all the other NT instructions are stores, except for `prefetchnta`.  The accepted answer here only seems to be talking about stores.  [This is what I've been able to turn up about NT loads](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32103968/non-temporal-loads-and-the-hardware-prefetcher-do-they-work-together).  TL:DR: hopefully the CPU does something useful with the NT hint to minimize cache pollution, but they don't override the strongly-ordered semantics of "normal" WB memory, so they do have to use the cache.

Comment: Update: NT *loads* may not do anything useful except on UCSW memory regions on most CPUs (e.g. Intel SnB family).  NT/streaming *stores* definitely work on normal memory, though.

Comment: @Peter: You mean USWC memory right? I've never heard of UCSW or USWC memory before. Googling the wrong acronym wasn't helpful :-)

Comment: @AndrewBainbridge: Yes, the WC memory type attribute.  Uncacheable Speculative Write-Combining.  I think I was capitalizing UnCacheable and remembering that it was supposed to be 4 letters long. :P

Answer (score 191, accepted):

Non-Temporal SSE instructions (MOVNTI, MOVNTQ, etc.), don't follow the normal cache-coherency rules. Therefore non-temporal stores must be followed by an SFENCE instruction in order for their results to be seen by other processors in a timely fashion.

When data is produced and not (immediately) consumed again, the fact that memory store operations read a full cache line first and then modify the cached data is detrimental to performance. This operation pushes data out of the caches which might be needed again in favor of data which will not be used soon. This is especially true for large data structures, like matrices, which are filled and then used later. Before the last element of the matrix is filled the sheer size evicts the first elements, making caching of the writes ineffective.

For this and similar situations, processors provide support for non-temporal write operations. Non-temporal in this context means the data will not be reused soon, so there is no reason to cache it. These non-temporal write operations do not read a cache line and then modify it; instead, the new content is directly written to memory.

Source: http://lwn.net/Articles/255364/

Comment: Nice answer, I would just like to point out that on the kind of processor with NT instructions, even with a non-non-temporal instruction (i.e. a normal instruction), the line cache is not "read and then modified". For a normal instruction writing to a line that is not in the cache, a line is reserved in the cache and a mask indicates what parts of the line are up-to-date. This webpage calls it "no stall on store": http://www.ptlsim.org/Documentation/html/node30.html . I couldn't find more precise references, I only heard about this from guys whose job is to implement processor simulators.

Comment: Actually http://www.ptlsim.org/ is a web site about a cycle-accurate processor simulator, exactly the same kind of thing the guys who told me about "no stall on store" are doing. I'd better mention them too in case they ever see this comment: http://unisim.org/

Comment: From the answers and comments here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44864033/make-previous-memory-stores-visible-to-subsequent-memory-loads it seems `SFENCE` may be not needed. At least in the same thread. Could you also look?

Comment: @SergeRogatch it depends on what scenario you are talking about, but yes there are scenarios where `sfence` is required for NT stores, whereas it is never required just for normal stores. NT stores aren't ordered with respect to other stores (NT or not), _as seen by other threads_, without an `sfence`. For reads from the same thread that did the stores, however, you never need `sfence`: a given thread will always see its own stores in program order, regardless of whether they are NT stores or not.

Comment: `Therefore non-temporal stores must be followed by an SFENCE instruction in order for their results to be seen by other processors in a timely fashion.` I don't know why `non-temporal stores must be followed by an SFENCE`. Then `non-temporal stores` doesn't allow memory reordering?

Comment: @SungJinKang because non-temporal stores are weakly-ordered, so fences are needed if multi-cores access the destination

Answer (score 47):

Espo is pretty much bang on target. Just wanted to add my two cents:

The "non temporal" phrase means lacking temporal locality. Caches exploit two kinds of locality - spatial and temporal, and by using a non-temporal instruction you're signaling to the processor that you don't expect the data item be used in the near future.

I am a little skeptical about the hand-coded assembly that uses the cache control instructions. In my experience these things lead to more evil bugs than any effective performance increases.

Comment: question about "hand-coded assembly that uses the cache control instructions." I know you explicitly said "hand-coded" what about something like a JavaVM. Is this a better use case? The JavaVM/Compiler has analyzed the static and dynamic behavior of the program and uses these non-temporal instructions.

Comment: Exploiting known locality properties (or lack thereof) of your problem domain, algorithm or application shouldn't be shunned. Avoiding cache pollution is indeed a very attractive and effective optimisation task. Also, why the aversion toward assembly? There are vast amounts of opportunities for gains available which a compiler cannot possibly capitalise on

Comment: It's definitely true that a knowledgeable low-level programmer can outperform a compiler for small kernels. This is great for publishing papers and blogposts and I've done both. They're also good didactic tools, and help understand what "really" going on. In my experience though, in practice, where you have a real system with many programmers working on it and correctness and maintainability are important, the benefit of low-level coding is almost always outweighed by the risks.

Comment: @Pramod that same argument easily generalises to optimisation in general and is not really in scope of the discussion -- clearly that trade-off has already been considered or otherwise been deemed irrelevant given the fact that we are already talking about non-temporal instructions

Answer (score 11):

According to the Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual, Volume 1: Basic Architecture,
"Programming with Intel Streaming SIMD Extensions (Intel SSE)" chapter:

**Caching of Temporal vs. Non-Temporal Data**

> Data referenced by a program can be temporal (data will be used again) or non-temporal (data will be referenced once and not reused in the immediate future). For example, program code is generally temporal, whereas, multimedia data, such as the display list in a 3-D graphics application, is often non-temporal. To make efficient use of the processor’s caches, it is generally desirable to cache temporal data and not cache non-temporal data. Overloading the processor’s caches with non-temporal data is sometimes referred to as "polluting the caches". The SSE and SSE2 cacheability control instructions enable a program to write non-temporal data to memory in a manner that minimizes pollution of caches.

Description of non-temporal load and store instructions.
Source: Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual, Volume 2: Instruction Set Reference

**LOAD (MOVNTDQA—Load Double Quadword Non-Temporal Aligned Hint)**

> Loads a double quadword from the source operand (second operand) to the destination operand (first operand) using a non-temporal hint if the memory source is WC (write combining) memory type [...]
>
> [...] the processor does not read the data into the cache hierarchy, nor does it fetch the corresponding cache line from memory into the cache hierarchy.

Note that, as Peter Cordes comments, it's not useful on normal WB (write-back) memory on current processors because the NT hint is ignored (probably because there are no NT-aware HW prefetchers) and the full strongly-ordered load semantics apply. `prefetchnta` can be used as a pollution-reducing load from WB memory

**STORE (MOVNTDQ—Store Packed Integers Using Non-Temporal Hint)**

> Moves the packed integers in the source operand (second operand) to the destination operand (first operand) using a non-temporal hint to prevent caching of the data during the write to memory.
>
> [...] the processor does not write the data into the cache hierarchy, nor does it fetch the corresponding cache line from memory into the cache hierarchy.

Using the terminology defined in [Cache Write Policies and Performance](http://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/Compaq-DEC/WRL-91-12.pdf), they can be considered as write-around (no-write-allocate, no-fetch-on-write-miss).

Finally, it may be interesting to review [John McAlpin notes about non-temporal stores](https://sites.utexas.edu/jdm4372/2018/01/01/notes-on-non-temporal-aka-streaming-stores/).

Comment: SSE4.1 `MOVNTDQA` only does anything special on WC (uncacheable Write-Combining) memory regions, e.g. video RAM.  It's not at all useful on normal WB (write-back) memory on current HW, the NT hint is ignored and the full strongly-ordered load semantics apply.  `prefetchnta` can be useful, though, as a pollution-*reducing* load from WB memory.  [Do current x86 architectures support non-temporal loads (from "normal" memory)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40096894).

Comment: That's correct, NT stores work fine on WB memory, and are weakly-ordered, and are usually a good choice for *writing* large regions of memory.  But NT loads aren't.  The x86 manual on paper allows for the NT hint to do something for loads from WB memory, but in current CPUs it does *nothing*.  (Probably because there are no NT-aware HW prefetchers.)

Comment: I have added that relevant info to the answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: @PeterCordes so I assume using a non temporal store on WB memory only has the benefit of weak ordering and doesn't override the WB to make it behave like WC memory of anything. But what actually is the benefit of having weakly ordered stores on WB memory, could you think of a specific scenario?

Comment: @LewisKelsey: NT *stores* do override the memory type.  That's why they can be weakly ordered on WB memory.  The major effect is avoiding RFOs (apparently they send an invalidate that even clears other dirty lines when they reach mem).  They can also become visible out-of-order, so they don't have to wait until after an earlier cache-miss (regular) store commits, or until an earlier cache-miss *load* gets data.  i.e. the kind of bottleneck asked about in [Is memory outside each core always conceptually flat/uniform/synchronous in a multiprocessor system?](//stackoverflow.com/q/56268226).

Comment: @PeterCordes do you know if the non temporal hint also makes UC and WP writes weakly ordered in the store buffer? (despite the fact that UC and WP overrides the hint from the cache perspective)

Comment: @LewisKelsey: In other cases, like an `monvtdqa` *load*, overriding the memory type means it's still strongly ordered.  So I think the fact that UC and WP override the NT hint fully means strong ordering.

Comment: @PeterCordes yeah I've seen that and I've read that part of the manual but I'm unsure about whether WP and UC are still weakly ordered **by the memory scheduler** (because it doesn't know the cache policy at this stage? I presume it's only knowledge of the L1d cache, which performs the TLB lookup after it's been dispatched to the L1d cache by the memory scheduler. I don't know the full details of this interaction). The L1d cache however will read and ignore the hint from the store buffer, treating it as WP or UC rather than USWC, as the manual says.

Comment: @LewisKelsey: A memory ordering machine clear could kill any loads from after a UC store that shouldn't have been done early, if necessary.  Other than that, commit order doesn't come into play until after the store retires from the out-of-order back end.  That can't happen until after the store-address uop has executed, at which point the memory type for the address can be checked.  A store-address uop checks the TLB when it executes; that's how CPUs can detect faulting stores before they retire.  It can't wait until the SB entry is ready to commit to L1d; at that point execution is past it.

Comment: @PeterCordes yes whereas privileges for a load are returned and checked on retirement hence meltdown, because the privileged load could be speculative and you only want to trigger the exception if it isn't speculative because then there never has to be such a thing as cancelling an exception microroutine or any such overhead

Answer (score 0):

To add context to these answers:

When you do a memory copy, the processor will typically do a read from the source (RS), then do a read from the destination (RD), and finally, when the cacheline is flushed, a write to the destination (WD).

By using the non-temporal intrinsic, you are providing a hint that the RD may not need to occur, and possibly that the cacheline should be prioritized for eviction. Intel's own documentation doesn't mention the need to do fencing [https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#ig_expand=0,6555,6556&text=movnt], so this probably isn't something that you would need to worry about.

Intel's guidance on non temporal code suggests it may impact performance in unexpected ways, for instance:

```
/**
 * @brief GCM-AES Encryption using 128 bit keys, Non-temporal data
 *
 * Non-temporal version of encrypt has additional restrictions:
 * - The plaintext and cyphertext buffers must be aligned on a 64 byte boundary.
 * - In-place encryption/decryption is not recommended. Performance can be slow.
 *
 * @requires SSE4.1 and AESNI
 */
```

[https://github.com/intel/isa-l_crypto/blob/master/include/aes_gcm.h]

As a rule of thumb, you probably shouldn't use the non-temporal version of the MOV instructions unless you need it (i.e. avoid premature optimization). An easy way to visualize if optimizations are needed are tools like Intel Performance Monitor Counter [https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/tool/performance-counter-monitor.html]. This tool can show you your actual bandwidth to/from memory and if your expected usage doesn't match your actual usage the NT instructions might be a good fix.

Lastly, if you are in a position to only target newer Intel processors, just use AVX512, which reads and writes one cacheline at at a time. This avoids any chance of an extra RD without causing a potentially incorrect hint.