# How if mfence is separated as two fences

Tags: memory-barriers

How if `mfence` is separated to `afence` and `bfence`, `afence` is for `load & store` reordering and `bfence` is for `store & load` reordering. What will happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the context is x86.  In addition to load-store and store-load reordering, `mfence` also prevents store-store reordering and load-load reordering.  Though normal stores on x86 cannot be reordered, "[non-temporal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37070/what-is-the-meaning-of-non-temporal-memory-accesses-in-x86)" stores can be reordered.